# How to solve nonlinear partial differential equation with two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

somehow, I got this partial differential equation but I don't know how should I start.

$$
a\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\left[
\frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t}+bg(x,t)\left[g(x,t)-f(x,t)+C\right]
+bd\frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}
-h\frac{\partial^2 g(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{g(x,t)}{j}-k\right]
+
l\frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}\left[
\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}+mf(x,t)\left[g(x,t)-f(x,t)+C\right]
-md\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}
-n\frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{f(x,t)}{p}-k\right]
=0
$$

where a, b, C, d, h, j, k, l, m, n, and p are constants.

Does the laplace tranform work in this PDE?

How do I laplace transform

$$
\frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}
\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}
$$

term?

Or is there any way I can solve other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nonlinear PDE, so Laplace transform is unlikely to help.

Also, it's one equation but with two dependent variables $f$ and $g$.  You might make a more-or-less arbitrary choice for one of them, and hope to solve (at least locally) for the other.

Some easy solutions are obtained by assuming $f$ or $g$ depends only on $t$.